# Using Python-docx to update cell content of a table

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm using `python 2.7 Python-docx` to try and modify the contents of cells in a table that is in a Microsoft docx document.  I opened the document as xml so I could get a look at where things are and try to get values so I can reference them.  Below is what I found.

```
<w:tbl>
<w:tblPr>
   <w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/>
   <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
   <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/>
</w:tblPr>
<w:tblGrid>
   <w:gridCol w:w="1345"/>
   <w:gridCol w:w="3148"/>
   <w:gridCol w:w="3148"/>
   <w:gridCol w:w="3149"/>
</w:tblGrid>
<w:tr w:rsidR="002C543C" w14:paraId="4C33FE0D" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidTr="009E290C">
  <w:trPr>
    <w:cantSplit/>
    <w:trHeight w:hRule="exact" w:val="1080"/>
  </w:trPr>
  <w:tc>
    <w:tcPr>
      <w:tcW w:w="1345" w:type="dxa"/>
    </w:tcPr>
    <w:p w14:paraId="4497FDDB" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="002C543C" w:rsidRDefault="002C543C">
       <w:pPr>
           <w:rPr>
             <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
             <w:sz w:val="24"/>
             <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
           </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
    </w:p>
  </w:tc>
  <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="3148" w:type="dxa"/>
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w14:paraId="15F285F0" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="002C543C" w:rsidRDefault="002C543C" w:rsidP="009E290C">
        <w:pPr>
        <w:jc w:val="center"/>
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
       <w:sz w:val="24"/>
     <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
     </w:rPr>
   </w:pPr>
   </w:p>
   <w:p w14:paraId="140917B0" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="009E290C" w:rsidRPr="001261E4" w:rsidRDefault="009E290C" w:rsidP="009E290C">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:jc w:val="center"/>
      <w:rPr>
       <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
      <w:b/>
      <w:sz w:val="24"/>
      <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
     </w:rPr>
     </w:pPr>
     <w:r w:rsidRPr="001261E4">
  <w:rPr>
  <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
  <w:b/>
  <w:sz w:val="24"/>
  <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>this is cell (1, 2)</w:t>
  </w:r>
  </w:p>
```

So using the above xml as reference below is what I tried implement to update the cell (0,0).

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.oxml.table import CT_Tbl
from docx.oxml.text.paragraph import CT_P
from docx.table import Table
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph


   f = open('filename.docx')
   doc = Document(f)
   table_to_update = Table('04A0', doc) # value from above <w:tblLook w:val="04A0"
   cell = table_to_update.cell(0, 0) # this produces the error 
   #cell.text = 'can we add something'
```

This code produces the following error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'col_count'
```

So I assume it's from the `04A0` value I'm sending in.  So first off I'm trying to find how to reference the table that I want to modify.  From there I want to find the cell within that table and modify that.  I've been looking for examples of this but haven't been able to find any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Table`'s constructor accepts `<w:tbl>` XML subtree and not the string id of the table (that's why it fails). Furthermore what you think is id is [actually](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa173811(v=office.11).aspx):

> Specifies what aspects of the table styles should be included. This is a bitmask of options: 0x0020=Apply header row formatting; 0x0040=Apply last row formatting; 0x0080=Apply header column formatting; 0x0100=Apply last column formatting.

---

You can get list of tables in the document by using following code:

```
doc = Document('filename.docx')
print(doc.tables)
```

Then you have to understand, which of the tables you need to modify (by position in the list or headers of the table or whatever applies). I will use the first table for simplicity. When you have you `Table` object you can modify cell values by doing:

```
table = doc.tables[0]
table.cell(0, 0).text = 'new value'
```

Then you can save updated document:

```
doc.save('filename_updated.docx')
```